# Can I determine length of numeric and decimal in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
CAST(CASE WHEN table_name1 NOT IN ('520','620')
THEN SUM(table_name2) ELSE 0 END
as numeric(15,2)) as Weight
```

I don't know how to determine the length of numeric and decimal in the proper way.
Does Bigquery have the similar **numeric(15,2)** functions as normal SQL code?

Comment: Please post definitions for your two tables and include sample data.

Comment: What does this SQL do?  Can you explain its nature / purpose?

Comment: The `numeric(15,2)` is the destined [data type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) for the `CAST` function.

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy in BigQuery.  The answer is a precision of 38 and a scale of 9.

As the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric-types) states:

> The `NUMERIC` data type is an exact numeric value with 38 digits of precision and 9 decimal digits of scale. Precision is the number of digits that the number contains. Scale is how many of these digits appear after the decimal point.

That is, BigQuery does not have the same flexibility with `numeric`/`decimal` as other databases have.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Gordon Linoff is correct and that you can limit the decimal places to 2 by using `'round'`.

If needed, you can use the `ROUND()` function in the `SELECT` query to have an output containing two decimal places. For clarification please check the given link [1].

Query Example:

```
SELECT
 Id,
 ROUND(size,2) As Size
FROM 
`bigquery-public-data.github_repos.contents`
LIMIT 100
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#round